# How to pass current date into a query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to pass sysdate into my query and respective result but I'm getting no record.

```
SQL> select  PROC_PD_CD from PS_PROC_PD where PD_STRT_DT = sysdate
  2  ;

no rows selected
```

Comment: Does ```date = NOW()``` work?

Comment: Add sample data to your question.  Also, include the database types, if you are not storing the values as date/times.

Comment: @vkuo: there is no `now()` function in Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the current date, you can get it using `sysdate`.  If your field has no time component:

```
select PROC_PD_CD
from PS_PROC_PD
where PD_STRT_DT = trunc(sysdate);
```

Otherwise:

```
select PROC_PD_CD
from PS_PROC_PD
where PD_STRT_DT >= trunc(sysdate) and
      PD_STRT_DT < trunc(sysdate + 1);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply I'm getting "no rows selected" both query

Comment: Then your data must be incorrect because the above is correct. It's hard to tell whats happening without sample data.

Comment: I have data below like PROC_PD_CD           PD_STRT_DT 
--------------------          ----------- 
W2005001                 29-DEC-2014 
W2005002                16-AUG-2015

Comment: @akhileshchand - please add sample data to the question, not as a comment. It would be helpful to show the column datatypes too.

Answer (score -2):

The SQL Server is GETDATE() for datetime, and CAST(GETDATE() as date) for just the date part.

Comment: thanks for ur reply I'm asking about oracle server.

Comment: Okay.  Probably want to state that in your question, and remove the 'sql' tag, as I inferred that you wanted to know about both Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: The SQL tag is for the language, not SQL Server. It's appropriate to have it on an Oracle-specific question.

Comment: It was tagged Oracle originally... There's also no need to cast `GETDATE()` to a date in SQL Server, it's already a date.